# how to call user defined mongoDB function in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have created one function in mongodb and want to call it from c# driver, I tried to search but was unable to get any related result regarding the same. I am using mongodb 3.2 version and  mongodb C# driver version is 2.2.3.3
So any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I am also stuck on this same problem.

Comment: same here. Creating BSON document for aggregate pipeline in c# is sweaty